# Trying to understand basic matrix multiplications in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am having trouble understanding an error I am getting in numpy. From linear algebra I know that `A.T@b.T=(b@A).T` where @ is a dot product and .T is the transposed matrix. However in numpy I am getting the follow error:

```
a = np.arange(4).reshape(1,4)
b = np.arange(4*3*2*5).reshape(4,3,2,5)
a@b

File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (4,3,2,5) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 2)
```

However `b.T@a.T` works just fine. So my question is: why does `(b.T@a.T).T` work and why does `a@b` not work?

Comment: Read the doc it is already explained.

Comment: @julien where can I find that?

Comment: Have you read how `@`, `matmul` matches up dimensions.  With a 2d and 4d it isn't trivial.  Keep in mind that for 'plain' linear algebra, `dot` is a 2d interacting with a 2d.  Using a 4d requires some sort of extension to the concept.

Comment: @hpaulj no, so that's why I am asking. Where can I find this?

Comment: Do you know google? "numpy dot" gives you https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html first choice...

Comment: `b` is not a matrix. A matrix is an order-2 tensor. `b` is an order-4 tensor. Did you mean `b` to be a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

The way I interpret:

```
b.T @ aT is 
(5,2,3,4) @ (4,1) => (5,2,3 1)
```

The last dimensions `dot`, and the (5,2) 'goes along for the ride':

```
(3,4) @ (4,1) => (3,1)
```

That is, proper `dot` is last dimension dotted with second to the last, the 4's match

The docs for `@`, `matmul` are https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul

> If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of matrices residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly.
>
> If both arguments are 2-D they are multiplied like conventional matrices.

In 
    a@b is (1,4) @ (4,3,2,5)

the (1,4) does not match up in any way with the last 2 dimensions of b, the (2,5)

```
In [158]: a@b
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-158-a832bb91e25d> in <module>()
----> 1 a@b

ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (4,3,2,5) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 2)
```

The last dim of `a` is 4.  It does not match the 2nd to the last of b, which is 2.

---

In einstein notation, `a` and `b` can be 'dotted' with:

```
In [159]: np.einsum('ij,jklm->iklm',a,b).shape
Out[159]: (1, 3, 2, 5)
```

Note that the `j` dimension is the one that the 2 arrays have in common.

```
In [160]: np.einsum('ijkm,ml->ijkl',b.T, a.T).shape     # pairing the m's
Out[160]: (5, 2, 3, 1)
```